# Linking large db from MariaDB to Ms access - getting "ODBC – call failed. (Error 3146)"

Tags: ms-access, odbc, synology, mysql-odbc-connector

I have an app that I have written on ms access that has a database on ms sql express.
Recently I bought Synology NAS with  phpMyAdmin of mariaDB installed, and I want to move my db to the mariaDB server.

I figured how to move the DB that I already have to my phpMyAdmin DB but I'm having trouble linking the db on phpMyAdmin to ms access.

I have tried both mariaDB ODBC and MySQL ODBC. I am able to connect to both of the drivers from ms access, and even link a very small table I created (four columns), but when I try linking the actual, way longer tables' I get "**ODBC – call failed. (Error 3146)**".

Please, if anyone knows how to solve this it'll be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this link could help you with your problem, otherwise there is a entry according this problem on microsofts website itself.

https://www.accessrepairnrecovery.com/blog/how-to-fix-ms-access-run-time-3146-odbc-call-failed-error?bcsi-ac-1890e3206a556864=2791AF9A00000002eK2ymznqLGBxTGEpp12oOI5jP67qCwAAAgAAAJzALACEAwAAEwAAANAOCAA=